# How to link Monero GUI wallet to Ledger Nano x

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

windows 10 desktop - ledger-live-desktop-2.8.0-win. Installed all. GUI accounts set up and montero loaded. Just want to move crypto to ledger hardware wallet.

Comment: Please see the guide I linked as well as MTP's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need following things checked before you even start:

1. Ledger Nano X with the most fresh Firmware (IMPORTANT!). Check if there is an update in Ledger Live app. If there is, update the Firmware first.
2. The newest, Monero App installed on Ledger Nano X
3. Monero GUI installed on your computer

I personally, like to make "dummy" wallet first in Monero GUI (Just click Create New Wallet). By doing so you can fully synchronize the Node with blockchain before you even start playing with your hardware wallet. When Blockchain is fully synchronized on the Node, you can create a second wallet which will be "hardware" wallet.

Basically what you need to do is to follow the instructions below:

- https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/en/ch02.md
- https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006352934-Monero-XMR-

First is the instruction from Monero GUI Guide (There is pdf in your Monero GUI folder). Latter is instruction from Ledger support page. Both should help you connect your hardware wallet to Monero GUI.

When you are done, you can simply send your Monero to the wallet address which is visible in Monero GUI as well as on your Ledger Device (They should match).

In case of any trouble let us know.